# Application database protection

Tags: android, database

I’m working on an Android application and one of the requirements is that application database has to be protected against access and modification from third parties, having in mind that this is possible with rooted devices my proposal is to use the database encryption feature, so no one can read or modify the database, even if they can access to the file. My doubt is: there’s another way to protect user’s data from third parties access? or this is the only way?

EDIT: another detail is that I'm using a NoSQL database and user's data is synchronized with a remote server.

Comment: where are you going to put the key to that encryption? if its bundled in your app then that defeats the purpose

Comment: I'm not sure yet, I'm just thinking on a solution to protect data from modification.

Answer (score 0):

@Shmuel encrypting the db with a key which even if stored is plain text is source code should be fine, if the goal is to protect data from being accessed by other apps on the phone, I don't see how an app installed on the phone could gain access to the source code to fetch the key and decrypt it.

On the other hand if a person decompiles your app, yes that is a security risk. You could use local variables such as uuid of the phone along with some other unique id to encrypt the data so that way each user has a unique encryption key. This way the owner of the data would be able to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your edit, it sounds like you want to use Firebase Database
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

It is secure, non relational, and synchronizes seamlessly with the web data storage.